# How to move questions from stackoverflow to dba

Tags: discussion, support, migration

I know some questions were migrated from SO to dba.SE. My question is how can one one flag that a particular question be moved to DBA. I have reputation around 1400 on SO. How can on do it?

I found this question and I though this is DBA related but it might not be.

[Should I use Roles or Schemas to give users access based on their department?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714877/roles-vs-schema)

Also I want to know how strictly this rule is followed that dba related question should be migrated to DBA although SO is also programming related forum.

Comment: flag it for moderator attention, mentioning ,"please migrate this question to this site.

Comment: @Lucifer did that. Thanks. Would also like to know how strictly this rule is followed just for my information.

Comment: rule ?????? which one ? sorry didnt get you properly

Comment: The rule is not followed strictly at all. If a question has a good chance of getting good answers on SO, it can stay.

Comment: Interestingly this question is now closed as off topic.

Answer (score 9):

That question is not a good candidate for migration for several reasons.

1. It's already answered on the site where it was asked.  Migrating it now probably won't result in any more answers.
2. It was asked in 2009.  Only new and active questions should be migrated between Stack Exchange sites.
3. It's probably already been asked and answered on DBA, so migrating it might create a duplicate. (Please check the target site before flagging for migration.)
4. It doesn't have a lot of detail to begin with.  I wouldn't consider that a great question that the community on DBA would be eager to have on their site.  (They might not *mind* having it on their site, but I don't think anyone would actively seek to have it migrated.)

Answer (score 2):

Like Lucifer said, just flag it as " it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate" and next "is off topic", and add a little comment to explain what.

I was facing of the same situation, but there is no strict rules.
So, the clues for deciding where you had to post, as far as I understand it, is :

- That's related to a programming (CRUD, performance, requests error, ORM, ...) --> SO
- That's related to administration (high availability, configuration, memory/IO/CPU usage) --> dba

Once again, there is no specific rules, just "a feeling".

You may receive good answers on both sites ;)

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way:

On which site would the question have the best chance of getting a good answer? That is... should the question be answered by a developer or a DBA?

That is what the mod will consider when reviewing your flag to move it. If you don't know which would be better, I would suggest leaving it be (if a question truly crosses the boundaries between dev and DBA, for instance).